# How to prove this language is not regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

$L = \{a^mb^n \ | \ (m,n)=1\}$

How can i prove this language is not regular? I tried pumping lemma for $a^mb^{m+1}$ but didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $p$ is the pumping length and $m \geq p$, what can you say about $(mnp, n)$?